# Jquery Mobile - onclick not working

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, listview, jquery-mobile

The function occurs before anything is clicked...
such as
[image]

When i click the name ^ fdsa, for exampmle, i need the id to pop up, but it automatically happens when the page is loaded for some reason

HTML

```
<ul data-role="listview" id="ccontent" data-inset="true">

</ul>
```

JS

```
function getClubs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: '',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ccontent').empty();
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
            $('#ccontent').append('<li><a href=\"#\"+onclick=\"' + getData(json[i].id) + '\" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
            $('#ccontent').listview('refresh');
        },
    });
}

function getData(id) {
    $('#clubcontent').append ('<li>'+id+'</li>');
    $('#clubcontent').listview('refresh');
};
```

Comment: i cant see `click` function in your code? EDIT: Oh, got it inline javascript. Remove that and use `.on('click')` callback function. Also, the ID of the listview is ccontent or cconttent?

Comment: @joe that was just a mistake i made while typing it onto stackoverflow

Comment: @Omar, how would I do that, could you give me an example in my situation

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is what you're looking for:

```
$(document).on('click', '#ccontent li a', function () {
    getData($(this).data('club-id'));
});

function getClubs() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'some url',
        crossDomain: true,
        type: 'post',
        data: '',
        success: function (data) {
            $('#ccontent').empty();
            var json = jQuery.parseJSON(data);
            for (var i = 0; i < json.length; i++)
            $('#ccontent').append('<li><a href="#" data-club-id="' + json[i].id + '" rel="external">' + json[i].name + '</a></li>');
            $('#ccontent').listview('refresh');
        }
    });
}
```

[`.on()`](http://api.jquery.com/on/) is used instead of an inline `onclick` event. `club-id` is used to store the `id` which is used in the `getData()` function.